# How to use a 'case' in VHDL blocks

Tags: vhdl

I want to re-use some code block and to make it more readable I tried to put it in a block. 
The code block is used to save some data to some buffers. This also includes a case statement. This block is used in a few states in a statemachine.

```
      someBlock: block
      begin
        destinationAddr <= destinationAddr_i;
        sourceAddr <= sourceAddr_i

        case type is
          when typeA =>
            someData <= dataA;
            dataLength <= 1;
          when typeB =>
            someData <= dataB;
            dataLength <= 2;
          when typeC =>
            someData <= dataC;
            dataLength <= 3;
        end case;

    end block;
```

The code is just an example of what I'm trying to do. I want this code to be inserted in the place I call someBlock.
If I make this block Sigasi and Vivado complain about the case statement. (mismatched input 'case', expecting 'end'). I placed the block declaration after the architecture begin but not inside a process.

Is this the wrong way to use a block? Is there some other way of making a 'function' that can manipulate all signals in the architecture?

edit:
ok figured it out. I tried using a procedure before, i placed it in the architecture but not in the process. The signals weren't accessible according to vivado because it couldn't be sure there wouldn't be multiple drivers (from different processes). If I place the procedure in the process it does work.

Thanks for the help everyone :)

Comment: What you are looking for is called `procedure`, similar to a function but directly affects signals

Comment: Don't use blocks. Nobody uses blocks.

Comment: I tried using procedures initially but then I need to give all affected signals as arguments and return them right? For my case there are about 10 affected signals and I don't really think that's a nice way of doing it. Or is there a way I can get these signals in scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, type is a reserved word and cannot be used for an object name. You also cannot use a case statement based on a checking an object type.

It is complaining because the inside of a Block statement is not a sequential region of the code. Case statements must be used in a sequential region, such as a process, function or procedure. In addition, blocks cannot be re-used, they are there simply to add a local region for scoping purposes.

To make it re-useable, you probably want to use a procedure instead. This would be declared in a declarative region - ie. before a "begin". Here is an example:

```
  procedure mux(constant s    : in  std_logic; 
                constant bits : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
                signal   o    : out std_logic
               ) is  
  begin
    case s is
      when '1'    => o <= bits(1);
      when '0'    => o <= bits(0);
      when others => o <= 'X';    -- for simulation only
    end case;
  end procedure;
begin

  -- create a synchronous mux
  process(clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      mux(s0, ipA, opA);
    end if;
  end process;

  -- you can call it outside a process also - this infers an async process, sensitive to s1, ipB, opB
  mux(s1, ipB, opB);

end architecture;
```

Comment: The code I submitted is not a copy of my code but more an explanation of what I'm trying to do. I have about 10 different signals that I want to save in buffers and I don't want to give a procedure 10 arguments and 10 return values (if 10 return values is even possible, probably not). Is there a way to make procedures use all the signals in the architecture?

Comment: Yes and no. Procedures have visibility of everything in scope, so you can read and affect signals and variables not in the parameter list (with some caveats) if they are in scope, but obviously this makes the code less portable and less reuseable. If you are trying to make a monolithic procedure, you're probably "doing something wrong". Maybe try breaking it down into smaller procedures. Or maybe even discrete entities.